# GA4 adding _gl parameter when cross-domain tracking is not set up

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-4

I have `UA and GA4` set up on a site for some time now.

Suddenly a couple of weeks ago, in-page anchor links started to have parameters like the below added to them, causing the page to reload on click.

The parameters look like this:

```
_gl=1*1sgncz4*_up*MQ..*_ga*NTU1ODYzNjQxLjE2ODM3Mjk0MTI.*_ga_BC9YG14JH3*MTY4Mz 
 cyODM5MS4zLjEuMTY4MzcyOTQxOC4wLjAuMA..
```

I'm aware this could be for cross-domain tracking, but have nothing set up in `GTM or GA4` for cross domain, and have also turned off all enhanced mesaurement / in-page link events but still had no luck finding what causes this.

Answer (score 3):

It can happen if `ad_storage` and `analytics_storage` cookie consents are set to `denied`. It allow passing ID parameters through URL without storing them in cookies.

You can debug it using Tag Assistant or, if you're advanced user, looking for `gcs` parameter in requests sent to GA4. gcs reflects consent status, for example, gcs=G111 means all consents are granted.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Did anything change recently? If these are set then _gl disappears but if nothing is set then _gl is added. This is a recent behavior.

Comment: @mayrop If "nothing is set" means the user neither accepts nor rejects cookies (no interaction with cookie pop-up), the result is all consent are (at least they have to be) set to "denied". So, _gl may be added if using GA4. Other cases need id-depth research.